# Why my downvotes to answers aren't part of the 2017 UI "achievements" reported change?

Tags: bug

I tried a few options of this question and nothing seems to match as having been asked.

I've been a pretty frequent "answerer" here since 2016/10. Accumulated a good rep. Lately I've been too busy with a project to actually answer despite having the time to "check in" on things with the two tags I frequent.

As such, while I've downvoted as usual, my answers have been much less frequent.

Today I had somebody accept an old answer - last June - more than a week *after* I down voted a few answers. All told, **today** I received 15 rep points but the green badge only (correctly) reported 13.

It's no big deal to me. But it's happened a few times now with this being the most obvious. Certain days (in the last 30) I should have received -2 points and while my total was correct the badge wasn't. So in the end it "caught up" I guess.

What's the correct things for me to do?

- Accept this as a *feature* and not a *bug*?
- Report it to (the proper) post on MSO? (If so, what is it?
- Don't be so picky? :-)

Postscript:

I just read through the 13 "Similar Questions" and only one looked promising. Unfortunately it's from 2014 and was a very different bug.

BUT - I also see where my usage of "badge" may be misinterpreted. I'm **not** speaking of SO badges you may earn (seen by your profile). I'm speaking about "badges" per iOS - and I believe all mobile devices - that may show *recent* things like unread email or messages....

Comment: So, just to see if this is what you meant (it's a tad unclear, perhaps a picture would help, if you get a chance to snag one?), are you saying that it's a bug that the negative rep is not appearing in the green icon that pops up on the "Achievements" menu icon on the top bar until other, positive, rep is gained?

Comment: I see this all the time, and assume it is a feature. The icon doesn't notify you of lost rep, it only notifies you of gained rep. For example, when you cast a downvote on an answer, it doesn't tell you that you lost 1 rep unless you expand it. It will however tell you that since the last time you opened the dialog, you've gained 14 rep, if you gained an accept too.

Comment: @Kendra, Kevin B explained it perfectly (and I'd accept it as the correct answer). I didn't want to post a screenshot because I felt that was *too* much info. Anyways, thanks. The explanation makes complete sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number on that icon represents the change in reputation since the last time you opened the dialog. If you opened the dialog then performed a few actions that resulted in you losing rep (like downvoting an answer,) when you come in the next day you'll see a weird number if you've earned enough rep to offset the lost rep since the last time you visited.

I see this pretty much daily

Comment: Thanks for answering. I vote/downvote/answer/open and receive upvotes less frequently (weekly) than I visit certain places on the site (daily for Q/A) so I'll take your word for this. Maybe I should have worded this as *"WHY do all upticks in rep show up automatically as a badge but these downticks do not?"*

Comment: That is a good question, though... if you think about it, it would be quite annoying if it popped up every time you cast a downvote to tell you that  you lost 1 rep for something you did. I have no idea if it shows negative rep from other sources, i fortunately get enough rep daily that that can't really happen.

Comment: New question.... how is it that your answer - which I would have accepted - is **already** accepted by someone? Does MSO operate differently than SO? So far I haven't done anything except voted your comment to my question as helpful. If the voting rules are different, where is the link for this?

Comment: It isn't accepted, are you confused by the checkmark UI color? only you see that

Comment: I'm confused by the checkmark period. (Yes, my questions on any SE site have been MSO - meaning no SO questions.) It seems counter-intuitive that someone who didn't ask the question could accept an answer, no matter the color. EDIT: Are you saying the checkmark only means it's a correct answer and the color means *who* accepted it?

Comment: No, the checkmark is a button that you can click to accept it, only you can click it

Comment: Ah, got it. It appears "greyed-out" only to me because I asked the question. Oops. I say an upvoted with the grey checkmark and thought *both* were caused by someone other than me. Thank you very much!